# Open Linux command in separate window and close it after the parent window is closed

Tags: python

I am looking for Python code which will run child's terminal with some Linux code and after exiting the parent terminal - all child's terminal will be closed.

Here is a little example how should it work:

```
import os

HOW_MANY_CHILDS_TERMINAL = 5

for x in range(HOW_MANY_CHILDS_TERMINAL):
    print("X opened.")
    os.system("do some linux stuff")
```

The problem is, this override my current terminal window.

I need to open each Linux command in separate window.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the command to the background with nohup https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm
or introduce threads and non-blocking operations.